# How do i get the 6 digits from the middle of a file path

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I have a file pathname like

```
/dbfs/mnt/dlg2stage/foldername/backupname/201906_load_1_20210623-151602.tar.tgz
```

I am trying to get only the six digits `201906`  digits and print them. I tried `sed` and `awk` but failed.

Comment: It's unclear whether you have the pathname in a variable or in a file or elsewhere, or whether you have a directory structure on disk with many files like these and you would want to extract the first part of the filename for each.  Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: To add... What are the qualifications of determining which six digits you want? Are they always going to be a six digit file name prefix? Will you ever need to handle a file name like "oops!201906_..." (where you added an "oops!" in front as a reminder of something)? What if you want "202106" extracted from "/some/path/202204_in_the_future/202106_hello_world!"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are actual files on your system, you can easily extract the part before the first `_` in the filenames of each file matching `*_*.tar.tgz` in the directory `/dbfs/mnt/dlg2stage/foldername/backupname` using a shell loop:

```bsh
for pathname in /dbfs/mnt/dlg2stage/foldername/backupname/*_*.tar.tgz; do
    name=$( basename "$pathname" )
    printf '%s\n' "${name%%_*}"
done
```

The `basename` utility will give you the filename portion of a pathname.  Given the example that you show, this would assign the string `201906_load_1_20210623-151602.tar.tgz` to the variable `name`. You could also have used `name=${pathname##*/}` to do the same thing (this parameter expansion removes the initial section of the string in `$pathname`, up to and including the last `/`).

The parameter expansion `${name%%_*}` would result in the longest trailing substring matching `_*` being removed from the value `$name`.  With the example shown, this would remove the first `_` character and everything to the right of it, leaving the substring `201906`, which is then printed using `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
file=/dbfs/mnt/dlg2stage/foldername/backupname/201906_load_1_20210623-151602.tar.tgz
```

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#c6)

first_6_digits_of_file_tail=${(M)${file:t}[0-9](#c6)}
```

Where `${file:t}` takes the *tail* of the file (its basename), `${(M)var#pattern}` returns the part at the start of `$var` that `M`atches the pattern.

POSIXly, you can use:

```
first_6_digits_of_file_tail=$(
  LC_ALL=C expr "/$file" : '.*/\([0-9]\{6\}\)[^/]*/*$'
)
```

`LC_ALL=C` to ignore the user's locale and consider all bytes as characters (the 128 first as per ASCII on most systems, including / and 0123456789 digits) so that `.` and `[^/]` be guaranteed to match bytes and `[0-9]` includes only 0123456789. It's not digits in `zsh` where ranges are based on codepoints and zsh considers each byte not otherwise forming part of valid characters as if it was a character.

Prepending `/` to avoid problems for values of `$file` that start with `-` or look like `expr` operators and also to guarantee the strings contains at least one `/` as expected by the regexp.

We don't allow `/`s after the `/XXXXXX` except at the very end to get the same behaviour as solutions using `basename` or zsh's `$file:t` where the basename of `/foo/bar/` or `/foo/bar////` is `bar`.

Beware it returns a false / failure exit status if there's no match but also if that sequence of 6 digits represents the 0 number (as in `/path/to/000000_whatever`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to print `201906` given that path string.  In that example, those six digits are: *the first six digits that have a slash in front of them*.

I'm putting the path into a variable just to make the command easier to read:

```bsh
% path_str='/dbfs/mnt/dlg2stage/foldername/backupname/201906_load_1_20210623-151602.tar.tgz'

% echo $path_str | sed 's/.*\/\([0-9]\{6\}\).*/\1/'
201906
```

Here's how I built up that match and replacement in **sed**:

- **`\/[0-9]\{6\}`**: matches a slash and 6 digits
- **`\/\([0-9]\{6\}\)`**: is the same, but now in a *capture group* or *sub expression* (the slash is not in the capture group)
- **`.*\/\([0-9]\{6\}\).*`**: matches everything before and after, so... *the whole line*
- **`\1`**: with the whole line matched, use the reference for the *first* (and only) capture group to replace the whole line with just the first 6 digits